# is there a way to use the forwarding of std::less<> and a custom compare at the same time with std::set/std::map?

Tags: c++, c++17

If I declare `std::set<std::string>` I get case-sensitive comparison.  If I want case-insensitive, I can write my own compare and declare like `std::set<std::string,cmpi>` and that works fine too.

```
struct cmpi { 
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        return strcasecmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) < 0;
    }
};
```

However, in high-use cases, I'm searching the `std::set` with a `const char *`, e.g. `find("string")` or `find(pszVar)` and unfortunately a temporary `std::string` (strlen, alloc, free) is created for the comparison operations.  I can avoid all that by using `std::set<std::string,std::less<>>` which forwards the type as-is with no temporary and works fine for case-sensitive compare.  But what about a case-insensitive compare version of that?

In this example I'm creating a class to ensure things are happening as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


class Str : public std::string {
public:
        Str(const char *s) : std::string(s) {
                std::cout << "create" << std::endl;
        }
        ~Str() {
                std::cout << "destroy" << std::endl;
        }

        bool operator<(const Str &s) const {
                std::cout << "local comparing Str:" << *this << " to Str:" << s << std::endl;
                return strcasecmp( c_str(), s.c_str() ) < 0;
        }
        bool operator<(const char *s) const {
                std::cout << "local comparing Str:" << *this << " to char*:" << s << std::endl;
                return strcasecmp( c_str(), s ) < 0;
        }
};


int main(void) {
        std::set<Str,std::less<>> list;
        list.emplace("A");
        list.emplace("D");
        list.emplace("C");
        list.emplace("b");
        for ( const auto &s : list ) {
                std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
        if ( auto s = list.find("c"); s != list.end() ) {
                std::cout << "found c!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
                std::cout << "c not found" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

4 creates for the emplaces, output order is `AbCD`, and no temporary create for the successful find.

So, is there a way to have the best of both worlds without having to declare two object types... a custom comparison that also forwards the comparison type?  I Tried a few variations of things, e.g. a namespace surrounding a templated std::less, named struct surrounding the operators so I could have two sets, etc. without success.

To reiterate: I don't want one or the other comparison type... I want to have both:

```
std::set<Str,std::less<>> list_no_case;
std::set<Str,????> list_case;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can avoid all that by using `std::set<std::string,std::less<>>`

No, you can avoid all of that by using a comparison function that does asymmetric comparisons, of which `std::less<>` is one example (and it only works because `std::string` has a `<` comparison operator with `char const*`). You can just write your own in `cmpi`. Just add additional `operator()` overloads to do comparisons between `std::string` and `char const*`.

```
using is_transparent = int;

bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const
{
    return strcasecmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) < 0;
}

bool operator() (char const *a, const std::string& b) const
{
    return strcasecmp(a, b.c_str()) < 0;
}

bool operator() (const std::string& a, char const *b) const
{
    return strcasecmp(a.c_str(), b) < 0;
}
```

Note that the `using is_transparent` part is needed to make this work. It's what a comparison uses to signal to the container that it allows asymmetric comparisons.

Comment: yes, however, if I use a named compare like std::set<std::string,cmpi> list; it no longer forwards the const char* type in the find, instead it creates a std::string temp... it doesn't utilize the const char* operators...

Comment: @mark: Sorry about that; there was a thing I forgot to do to properly signal the capability. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: yes thank you this is what I've been looking for!